# BuddyPress Profile And Cover Image Cannot Upload or Crop

Tags: wordpress, image, profile, buddypress, avatar

I noticed that a lot of people have this issue when they try to upload an avatar or a cover image to BuddyPress profile, they cannot see the image uploaded or crop it. You can see the file being uploaded successfully but when it comes to cropping, all you can see is a dot. It is very bad for anyone running on BuddyPress, you can't have a profile without a profile picture, right?

The error looks like this:

[image]

There is no obvious way to fix it, looking all over in BuddyPress settings or turning the php.ini from inside up to see if the upload size is too small. But since the upload process went well, it shouldn't be a system error.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that this is a compatibility issue with [Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/?aff=7365) lazy load image. Probably a bad thing when you're a [Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/?aff=7365) affiliate trying to promote Jetpack but it's the truth for most cases. To fix it, simply turn the lazy load off in Jetpack settings.

Turn the field circled in red off:
[image: Jetpack Lazy Loading for Image]

And voila, there you have it:
[image: BuddyPress Profile Cropping Me]

I'm sorry that I did not address this issue earlier, hope I've got it just in time. A [report](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/buddypress-compatibility-32/) of this have been filed to Jetpack, but if you would like, the more the merrier right?

Now since I'm still a [Jetpack](https://jetpack.com/?aff=7365) affiliate, Jetpack is still a very good security plugin for any WordPress site plus it's made by the company co-founded WordPress. It provides free brute force attack protection as well as downtime monitoring. It will send a very nice email whenever your site went down. Besides that, it also provides free CDN for any of you that needs it. If you have it installed already then you should know by now how useful it is, trust me, it worth more than this little inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to ensure that jetpack lazyload is not enabled on profile change avatar page.

```
function lazyload_exclude() {
    if (bp_is_current_component('profile') && bp_is_current_action('change-avatar')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'lazyload_is_enabled', 'lazyload_exclude', 15 );`
```